How can I locate via holes for PCB design?
I'm working on a PCB design (Artwork) and looking at the reference PCB layout for the EP4RKU+ (1-to-4 splitter), I see via holes overlapping with the GND pads. However, the PCB design (Artwork) guy who is working with me mentioned that if via holes are overlapping with the GND pads, the GND pads might get damaged, potentially causing issues when components are mounted.
From my perspective, as long as the components are soldered well, it doesn't seem like it would be a significant problem. What are your thoughts on this?
The PCB is a 4-layer board, and there are no other signal or power lines passing under via holes.


Overlapping via holes with GND pads can weaken the pad, making it prone to damage during the soldering process. This can cause issues with the mechanical stability of the solder joint, which might lead to component failure over time.

I've never heard of "damage" due to via-in-pad, could you provide more background on this @liaifat85 ?

Not much, but this thread discuss some difficulties with soldering due to via in pads. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/170209/anything-bad-to-place-a-via-on-a-pad

Some PCB houses can fill and plate over vias, although I’m not sure about partially plated-over.  If your PCB fabrication house is ok with it then there shouldn’t be a problem.  It’s not obvious though why the vias have been placed as they have; it would seem normal to put them a little further out, out of harm’s way.  That said, it’s an RF circuit so the writer of the datasheet perhaps wanted to be as faithful as possible to the reference design.  Conceivably it’s important/critical to the design.

Note that the device in question https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=EP4RKU%2B goes out to 18GHz! I agree, the placement of these vias will be important.

Thank you for the answer @Frog  and Tim!!
